# Why am I getting a jQuery 'ui.element is undefined' error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-1.3.2

I have the following:

```
$('#widgets ul').sortable(
{
  connectWith: ['#widgets ul'],
  opacity: 0.7,
  start: function(e, ui) {
    fromWidgetPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
    fromRowId = ui.element.attr('id');
```

I just upgraded jQuery from 1.2.6 to 1.3.2, and I also upgraded the jQuery UI library to the latest version.

Comment: Why isn't anything closed out in your code snippet?

Comment: It's a partial code snipped. I knew something was deprecated in that block, so the entire thing was not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'element' got removed in newer jQuery UI versions, see this [bug report](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4007) and the [corresponding source changeset](http://dev.jqueryui.com/changeset/1644).

According to those, you should use `$(this)` instead:

```
fromRowId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Ahem - could we go with the usual upvote/accept answer instead of the kissing?  ;)